# Update statement to convert Email to MD5 is not calculating the correct results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have trying to cycle through my database and MD5 hash my email addresses. This is the code I tired using:

```
update Recipients set MD5Email = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), HASHBYTES( 'md5', NonMd5.EmailAddress ), 2)
from 
 Recipients INNER JOIN Recipients as NonMd5
on 
 Recipients.Id = NonMd5.Id
```

I also tried this and it had the same result:

```
update Recipients set MD5Email = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), HASHBYTES( 'md5', Recipients.EmailAddress ), 2)
    from 
     Recipients
```

If I replace the NonMd5.EmailAddress with an a hardcoded string, it calculates it correctly. I have no idea what is wrong.

This is my Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Recipients] (
[Id] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT (newid()) ,
[EmailAddress] nvarchar(MAX) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL ,
[IsProcessed] bit NOT NULL ,
[MD5Email] nvarchar(80) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL ,
CONSTRAINT [PK__Recipien__3214EC0703317E3D] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
ON [PRIMARY]
TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Update:

If I set an email adress to test@test.com  this is my result:  `4767DCA4A82B295C59D18097EE7B4070`

Running it as a direct value in the code above, this is my result:

```
b642b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4452
```

Comment: Why is MD5Email nvarchar and not varbinary? If it is nvarchar why are you converting the output to varchar(max)? Why are you using MD5 instead of a stronger algorithm? Why are you using style 2 instead of style 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just:

```
UPDATE dbo.Recipients 
  SET MD5Email = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(80), HASHBYTES('MD5', EmailAddress), 2);
```

That said you really should consider SHA or other algorithms over MD5, and you really shouldn't be storing the hash output as a *string* - use varbinary.

Here are the results I get:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf899/1)

Now there is a very important distinction that I think you're missing. You're currently storing an e-mail address as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` - I have no idea why you're using Unicode (most servers in the world still don't support double-byte characters), and I have no idea why you're using `MAX`. However compare these:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(80), HASHBYTES('MD5', 'test@test.com'), 2);

SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(80), HASHBYTES('MD5', N'test@test.com'), 2);
----------- this N is very important ---------^
```

Given the current SMTP standard, your column should *probably* be 320 characters (255 characters for domain name, 64 for local part, plus the @ symbol) instead of `MAX` (nobody has an e-mail address with > 4000 characters, never mind 1 billion characters). And you would only need `NVARCHAR` if you truly need to support Unicode e-mail addresses - which, like I said, are unrecognized by most mail servers today. If you change the data type, you will see that it matches your test. If you stay with `NVARCHAR`, you need to compare apples to apples, so when you run your test, make sure you prefix your hard-coded value with an `N`.

Comment: I agree, but we get lists of MD5 encrypted emails from our clients that we have to compare to our lists.

Comment: @DDiVita What "result"? Could you be a little bit more specific, please? All you've said so far is "doesn't work" - what does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @DDiVita you can compare the incoming MD5 values using varbinary comparison just like string comparison. <shrug>

Comment: Looking at your Fiddle, the values are not correct either. Here is one I created hard coding one of your values: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf899/8

Comment: I understand that, but I still have the issue with the values not being correct.

Comment: Converting the columns to varchar helped. the N in front of the string made more sense and lead me to rethink this a bit. unfortunately , I inherited the database and didn't think much about the schema.